# Why does this method returns "System.String[ ]", instead of returning all the objects in the array?

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio

`wordlist()` method that returns a string array copied from a field in a struct.
But the problem is this method returns `System.String[ ]`, instead of returning all the objects in the array. I tried to do `foreach`, but I think that not the problem. I couldn't figure it out unfortunately.

```
public struct wordStruct
{
    public string Sword;
}   

class StringCounterClass : IOrederedWordStructure
{
    wordStruct[] array = new wordStruct[10];

    int totalInsertedWords = 0;

    public string[] wordList()
    { 
        string [] wordArray = new string[array.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < wordArray.Length; i++)
        {
            wordArray[i] = array[i].Sword;
        }

       return wordArray;
    }

    public void insertWord(string[] words)
    {
        int insertwordLength = words.Length;
        totalInsertedWords = insertwordLength;
        string[] myWord = words;

        foreach (string word in myWord)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < insertwordLength; i++)
            {
                array[i].Sword = myWord[i];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `}` for `wordList()` is wrongly placed,  i think its be a typo

Comment: This code won't even compile.  The `return` statement is outside of any method in the class.

Comment: Thanks for your observation, but the return statement is in the method block.

Comment: Not in the question. We cannot help you with the code you have on your own computer, we can only help you with the code you've posted. And the code you've posted is wrong.

Comment: Also, if it is a problem that the method returns a string array, why are you returning a string array? Or is it that you've used something like `Console.WriteLine(wordArray)` and is wondering why the output was `System.String[]` ?

Comment: Thanks, yes I did tried Console.WriteLine(wordArray[1]) something like that and it did work. but I'll put the whole work in a momet..

Comment: I just added the rest of the code, please let me know.

Comment: Even with your edited code, it's still not compilable. Count the curly braces here: `public string[] wordList() { ... { ... } ... } return wordArray;`. If you want help, *please* create a [mcve]

Comment: Not sure I get the question. `System.String[]` is the fully qualified name of `string[]` which is an array of strings which **is** "all the objects in the array", right? How do you come to the conclusion that this is not what you want? As @LasseV.Karlsen said, it's probably some (implicit) call to `ToString()` that will cause `"System.String[]"` to be returned/displayed. If you want to combine all the strings in the `string[]` into *one* (for example) space separated `string`, try: `string value = string.Join(" ", wordArray);`

Comment: I wanted the objects to be displayed one underneath another, also I tried the space separated code but still got the problem.

Comment: Please add the code that shows that `System.String[]`

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your typo

   ```
     } return wordArray;
   ```

   2. When did you fetched your values into the object **array** in your code. If that was not done properly, then you will have an empty array size of 10 in the object **array**. So obviously you will get an another empty array returned in your method.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I thought about that but I did verified whether the array.Sword empty or not by writing this code in the method block.. console.writeLine(array[1].Sword); and it did work. but the return won't work because of some reason.

Comment: I just added the rest of the code, please let me know.

Comment: I am still assuming that your return statement is within the method block {} in your actual code. 

Can you try doing the following code:

    public string[] wordList()
    { 
        string [] wordArray = new string[array.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            wordArray[i] = array[i].Sword;
        }
return wordArray;
     }

Comment: I got this mistake only here sir, but I get the same result.

Comment: Then I could not find any mistake in your code. Can you show me the code that calls this 2 methods inside the class "StringCounterClass" ? Just like to know when you are initializing the array and fetching it.

Comment: static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Class1 cs = new Class1();
            string[] myString = {"Bader", "Mike", "Conner"};

            cs.insertWord(myString);

            Console.WriteLine(cs.wordList());

            Console.ReadKey();

Comment: Again, try changing `Console.WriteLine(cs.wordList());` to `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", cs.wordList());` -- or, if you want every entry on a separate line: `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, cs.wordList());` or even `foreach(string word in cs.wordList()) { Console.WriteLine(word); }`

Comment: It is true that you cannot print the entire string like this--  
    Console.WriteLine(cs.wordList());     
You have to loop through it using foreach() like:

foreach(var word in cs.wordList()) 
 Console.WriteLine(word);

Comment: Yes, you cannot do what you (presumably) want to do like that. You need to loop (one way or another). -- `Console.WriteLine(cs.wordList());` will implicitly call `cs.wordList().ToString()`. But `cs.wordList()` is a `string[]` and has no special override for the method `ToString`. So `object.ToString()` will be executed, which just prints the name of the type of the object. **That's** where you get `"System.String[]"` from, because that is the type of the object.